# Is there still yibum if executed by beis din?

Tags: beit-din-court, yibbum-chalitza-levirate, capital-punishment

If a married man who is childless is executed by beis din, does his brother still have an obligation to perform yibum?

Comment: cyclops, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this question! You could make it even more valuable and answerable by [edit]ing in some background about the concepts involved and why you think this question arises. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: I can't imagine why there wouldn't be yibbum in this case.

Comment: I am confident that the Rambam discusses this in Mishneh Torah. When I get to that perek I will provide an answer.

Comment: According to the reason which the Torah gives itself which is to prolong the name of the fathers linage  should apply to this case as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[*Bamidbar* 27](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0427):3, quoting *Tz'lofchad*'s daughters, who were seeking land in Israel:

> אָבִינוּ מֵת בַּמִּדְבָּר וְהוּא לֹא הָיָה בְּתוֹךְ הָעֵדָה הַנּוֹעָדִים עַל ה׳ בַּעֲדַת קֹרַח כִּי בְחֶטְאוֹ מֵת…‏
>   Our father died in the desert; he was not among the group who met against God in the group of *Korach*, but died for his own sin…

[The *Sifre*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39751&pgnum=391) (ad loc.) comments:

> והוא לא היה בתוך העדה זו עדת מלינים הנועדים על ה׳ זו עדת מרגלים בעדת קרח זו עדה של קרח כי בחטאו מת שלא החטיא את אחרים עמו
>   "He was not among the group", the group of complainers; "who met against God", the group of spies; "in the group of *Korach*", the group of *Korach*; "but died for his own sin", that he did not cause anyone else to sin with him.

[*Malbim*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39751&pgnum=391) on the *Sifre*:

> היל״ל והוא לא היה בעדת קרח וע״כ הוציאו מאריכות הלשון שכללו כל הנועדים לחלוק על ה׳ כמו מתלוננים ומרגלים ועדת קרח ביחוד שכולם לא נטלו חלק בארץ… וגם י״ל מפני שעקר טענתם היתה מכח יבום ועדת קרח ואינך אין להם חלק לעוה״ב ולא שייך אצלם יבום לתקן נפש המת לז״א שהוא לא היה מכללם כי בחטאו מת ולא החטיא אחרים ומיתתו כפרה וי״ל חלק בארץ וחלק לעוה״ב
>   The *pasuk* should have merely said "he was not in *Korach*'s group"; from the extended description, the *Sifre* derived that the daughters of *Tz'lofchad* included *all* those who met to differ with *Hashem*, like the complainers and the spies and *Korach*'s group in particular, as *all* these had no portion of land in Israel…. One can also say that [they mentioned these groups] because their main claim was a *yibum*-type claim. *Korach*'s group and the others had no share in the world to come, so *yibum* has no bearing on them, as it does not fix their souls. So the daughters said that their father had not been in these groups — he died for his own sin, without causing others to sin — so his death is an atonement [for him] and he has a share in the land and in the world to come.

The *Malbim* is saying that *Tz'lofchad*'s daughters' claim was a *yibum*-type claim. While I don't know what he means by that, he definitely seems to be implying that anyone with a portion in the world to come could have *yibum*-type claims apply to them after death. [Most of those killed by *bes din* fall into this category](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%92#.D7.94.D7.9C.D7.9B.D7.94_.D7.95), and *yibum* would seemingly then apply.

(*Tz'lofchad* himself was killed by *bes din* —  he was the *m'koshesh* of [*Bamidbar* 15](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0415):32–36 — according to [*Rabi Akiva*](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=315). (Others differ.))