# Yibum & Chalitzah for a widow whose husband died by suicide

Tags: halacha, yibbum-chalitza-levirate, suicide

Do the halachos of Yibum and Chalitzah apply (*Rachmana Li'tzlan*, Hashem *Yishmor*) to the widow/ brother(s) of a person who died via suicide?

<sub>(ie is this type of death different than other types of deaths)</sub>

Comment: I don't understand what is the question, is it because he didn't want children?

Comment: @kouty does he receive a "penalty" (of sorts) for this and not have this mitzvah be applicable in this instance

Comment: Similar question about another random method of death also prompting yibbum https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16479/759

Answer (score 10):

It appears there is no difference between suicide and other forms of death as pertains to yibum and chalitza. Rabbi Moshe Rozin, a 20th century posek (Lithuania and New York) was asked to rule on the case of a widow whose husband had committed suicide and the whereabouts of the brother-in-law were unknown. (See footnote 71 herein [1](https://books.google.com.pe/books?id=M5NHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT127&lpg=PT127&dq=yibum%20%2B%20suicide&source=bl&ots=KNiED-3m8y&sig=ACfU3U33ozf5HYOnEnCcrvphZ2jHu0AMFA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN8a38obbkAhXr01kKHRqRAFgQ6AEwAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=yibum%20%2B%20suicide&f=false)). He found room for leniency and allowed her to remarry without chalitzah, but the manner in which her husband died was not germane to the ruling.